# Javascript Web API call in for loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am developing an app with angularjs and ionic. 
There I have an array with ids. And from all these ids I need to have a name. Now I tried it with the code below:

```
var arrayWithIds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
var arrayWithNames = [];

for (var j = 0; j < arrayWithIds.length; j++) {
    ResourceService.get(arrayWithIds[j]).then(function(resource) {
        arrayWithNames.push(resource.Name);                  
    },function(error) {
        alert(error.message);        
    });               
}

$scope.resources = arrayWithNames;
```

It is all ok when I debug. I always get the name back. But in $scope.resources there is nothing, it is empty, also the array arrayWithNames.

Do I miss something? What is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding in the _return arrayWithNames;_ at the end of the for loop? See whether that works?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe it is important to say that the whole code above is also in a web api call.

Comment: Please check the response variable names. Is Name or name.

Comment: @Ramesh: Thank you very much. That was the fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ResourceService.get()` call is asynchronous (and also a Promise), and this line

```
$scope.resources = arrayWithNames;
```

is getting called before the `ResourceService.get()` callback.

You can drop `arrayWithNames` and directly push to `$scope.resources`:

```
var arrayWithIds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
$scope.resources = [];

for (var j = 0; j < arrayWithIds.length; j++) {
    ResourceService.get(arrayWithIds[j]).then(function(resource) {
        $scope.resources.push(resource.Name);                  
    },function(error) {
        alert(error.message);        
    });               
}
```